# add reference to msvcr90.dll in .net project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll, msvcr90.dll

One of our self hosted customer, do not have the public installation of msvcr90.dll. In order to make our app work on their machine, after each deployment we manually add msvcr90.dll and Microsoft.VC90.crt file in our app folder. and this requires a restart of the machine. is there a way I can add these two files in the project and make my project reference these files? I tried adding msvcr.dll in the project but I am getting following error:

"A reference to msvcr90.dll could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component."

Answer (score 1):

I have that problem before same as yours but all i do is, Set the project to run as Administrator account and inside of the project, i manually code to copy the dll in system32 folder and it worked fine.

All DLL's can't be added into VS project. It depends on what framework, versions of DLL's came from. If not meet the requirements then VS project won't accept on it.